# Why does my screen go white?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, intel, samsung, white-screen

Ubuntu 12.04.

Ok, I don't know if it's my driver's fault or Ubuntu's fault or mine.

But while in Ubuntu my laptop's screen goes all white when not adjusting anything to the screen. I don't know why, or how. I am suspecting it is Ubuntu because when I adjust the brightness it changes the brightness on the white, instead of adjusting Ubuntu's brightness. How do I stop the white coming up like that?

Here are my Labelled Specs:

> Samsung NC10 with Intel Atom Inside
>
> Connected with Vodafone
>
> Energy Star

Those were the labels on my computer. These are the proper specs: (I'm only doing the screen, but if you require more, just ask)

> Processor: Intel® Atom™ processor N270 (1.6GHz, 533MHz, 512KB, 2.5W)
>
> Display: LCD 10.1 / 10.2" WSVGA (1024 x 600) LED Anti-Glare Display
>
> Graphics:
>
> Graphic Processor: Intel® 945GSE (Integrated Graphics)
>
> Graphic Memory: Intel® 945GSE 128MB Integrated Graphics
>
> VGA: Yes

So, is there anyway to get rid of that blank white screen?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can confirm this issue on with 12.04 running on a Samsung NC10. You may (partly) overcome this by installing the Voria tools for brightness adjustment from the following [ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them):

- [ppa:voria/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa)

We are also able to read about these tools on the [Voria Forums](http://www.voria.org/forum/).

On our netbook these issues did not resolve completely, and are mostly present when the power cord is plugged in (i.e. the system does not reduce brightness by default). Then we are only able to reduce the brightness using the keys after having logged in blindly.

**Additional note:** as we observed a dependency of this issue from the lid position we believe there is a (mechanical/electrical?) hardware issue involved.

Comment: Ok... I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Right, I had a look at the forms... but where's the question (And the answer?)

Comment: Oh, and I don't think it's the brightness. It might be a driver or something.

Comment: @nerof61: see edit why we believe that software/driver debugging may not lead to a good resolution.